Build ( NEXT.JS) hacia produccion genera siempre endpoint estático a localhost:3000 y no a mi ruta de servidor
Despues de hacer el build de producción, al probar un boton que llama a un endpoint veo que en lugar de hacerlo , por ejemplo, a https://miempresa.com/api/consulta lo hace a localhost:3000/api/consulta(como lo tengo en desarrollo,que funciona bien).
Creé entonces un archivo .env,entiendo que una variable que no viene precedida con NEXT_PUBLIC , en desarrollo lo toma como undefined, no así en produccion.
Siguiendo esa lógica cree una variable HOST:https://miempresa.com y cambié el codigo para que si HOST === undifined el endpoint sea localhost:3000/api/.... sino tome el valor que tiene process.env.HOST.
Pero veo que el build siempre me pone localhost:3000 en las ruta generadas. Mas allá que en produccion lee correctamente el process.env.HOST. Es decir que las rutas estáticas que me genera en .next siempre toma como localhost:3000.
No se me ocurre como hacer para que en desarrollo tome localhost:3000 pero en produccion tome la ruta del servidor . Espero se entienda.Si host lo dejo como 'https://miempresa.com' hago el build ,subo la carpeta .next y anda perfecto. El tema es que al seguir en modo desarrollo , tengo que cambiarlo a localhost:3000.
Aclaro que .env en desarrollo tiene localhost:3000 y en produccion tiene la ruta del servidor.
Gracias.
Gracias.
